# Passing a vector of lambdas to Rcpp's rpois

Tags: r, random, rcpp

Within R, `rpois` can be passed a vector of lambdas describing multiple Poisson distributions, e.g.

```
rpois(5, (1:5)*1000)

# [1] 1043 1974 3002 3930 4992
```

Above, each element of the output vector is drawn from a different Poisson distribution, with means of 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 and 5000, respectively.

If I have an `arma::mat` (using these because elsewhere I am using cubes) containing lambdas of Poisson distributions, what is the best way to pass these (one row at a time) to `rpois` within Rcpp?

Here's a toy example, and an excerpt from the ensuing error message:

```
library(inline)
library(RcppArmadillo)
code <- "
  using namespace Rcpp;
  using namespace arma;
  arma_rng::set_seed(42); // Dirk's seed of choice

  mat lam = randu(5, 5); // ignore the fact these are all 0-1
  mat out(5, 5);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    out.row(i) = rpois(5, lam.row(i));
  }      

  return(wrap(out));
"

f <- cxxfunction(body=code, plugin="RcppArmadillo")

# cannot convert 'arma::subview_row<double>' to 'double' for argument '2' 
#   to 'Rcpp::NumericVector Rcpp::rpois(int, double)'
```

I must admit my understanding of type conversion in c++ is quite poor. Is what I'm trying to do possible (my guess is no, since it seems `rpois` is expecting a double), or do I need to iterate over each cell of the matrix, generating a single deviate each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From C/C++, you have access to at least 2 Poisson deviate generation routines (search for `rpois` in this [online manual](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/index.html)).

Their declarations are as follows:

```
double R::rpois(double mu);
NumericVector Rcpp::rpois(int n, double mu);
```

None of them allows for passing > 1 values in `mu` (a.k.a. lambda). The first function is the R's original routine, used to implement `rpois` as we know from the R `stats` package (the one that is vectorized w.r.t. all its arguments). Given a single `mu`, it returns a single (pseudo)random deviate.

The second one is the so-called `Rcpp` sugar function. It allows to calculate `n` deviates at a time and return them as a `NumericVector` (again, by using `R::rpois`).

In other words, you should rather use two nested `for` loops to fill a matrix, by calling `R::rpois`. Don't be afraid of such an approach, this is C++. :)

Comment: A very useful answer, thank you. And a great tip about searching the online `Rcpp` manual. I've implemented your suggested approach now and it's working just fine :).